# Is Ubuntu and Kubuntu same in hardware compability?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kubuntu, software-recommendation, amd-graphics

So I found out that my video card only supports Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, 14.04.2. So I've decided to install Kubuntu 14.04.2, will there be any compability problems or am I good to go? I just really like how the Kubuntu looks like, but if I have to give it up, than it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine. The only difference between a release of Ubuntu and Kubuntu is that Kubuntu uses the KDE desktop environment instead of the Unity graphical environment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu lists what is different, only your graphical frontend and other applications that are part of the KDE project are different. Underneath the user interface and the list of default applications that are present on installation (you can install everything from Kubuntu on a vanilla Ubuntu install too, if you'd like) you're running the same operating system.

Comment: What's more, except for rare edge cases hardware (and drivers) supported by Unity is also supported by KDE and Gnome and vice versa since they use almost exactly the same graphics instructions.